# How to mount together a filesystem tree for use in openvz?

Tags: mount, openvz, quota

I want my vm to use a filesystem tree consisting of multiple filesystem mounted together:

```
mount <root-path> /var/lib/vz/private/<id>/
mount <home-path> /var/lib/vz/private/<id>/home/
```

Using this layout `vzctl start` fails since `vzquota` can not work on busy directories. `/var/lib/vz/private/<id>/` is busy since there is something mounted inside it.

How can I create such a filesystem tree and still use it for a vm?

## Some solutions which do not work

### `mount --bind`

When bind mounting a directory, the busy flag is preserved, and is therefore still preventing vzquota from working.

### `aufs`

Using `aufs` with only one source filesystem is much alike bind mounting. Unfortunately my root filesystem is already aufs, and aufs on debian squeeze cannot be used inside aufs itself.

Answer (score 0):

`mount --bind` does work, you are simply binding on the wrong directory.

You need to `mount --bind` on the `ROOT` directory defined in the `<VEID>.conf` file, something like:

```
mount --bind /what/to/bind /var/lib/vz/root/<id>/home/
```

Example script: http://wiki.openvz.org/Bind_mounts. This will make a `<VEID>.mount` directory which is called directly after the container is mounted.

Comment: If i mount directory to `/var/lib/vz/root/<id>/` will the disk quota be followed?